# Cambiar formato fecha Codeigniter 3 query builder

Tags: codeigniter-3, sql

```
$this->db->select("DATE_FORMAT(cliente.fecha_reserva, '%M %e, %Y') as formatted_date", FALSE);
```

Este código me arroja el siguiente formato : June 14, 2017

¿De que forma obtengo el formato dd/mm/yyyy ?

Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Funciones basicas de **DATE_FORMAT**

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT("2017-06-15", "%d/%m/%Y");
```

Copia el codigo de arriba y pegalo aqui:

**https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trymysql.asp?filename=trysql_func_mysql_date_format3**

En tu caso seria esto :

```
$this->db->select("DATE_FORMAT(cliente.fecha_reserva, '%d/%m/%Y') as formatted_date", FALSE);
```